# Google Script button_action fetching error

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to use Sniply API with the following Google Script code, yet I keep receiving an error message. Except the button configuration everything seems to work properly.

The code looks like:

```
  // Main Parmaters  
  var url = "picky.com"               
  var message = "This is a text from the Google Spreadsheet API2"            
  
  // Button Parameters (Optional)
  var button_text   = "I am a button2"                
  var button_url =  "mailto:info@picky.com"   
  var button_background_color = "#000000"       
  var button_text_color = "#ffffff"            
  
  // Button (Optional)   
  var button_action =
      {
        "text": button_text,
        "url": button_url,
        "text_color": button_text_color,
        "background_color": button_background_color, 
        
      }
  
  var sniply =
      {
        
        "button_action": button_action,
        "url": url,
        "message": message,
      }
  
  var options = 
      {
        "method": "post",
        
      
        "headers" : {
          "Authorization" : accesstoken,    
        }, 
        "payload": sniply,
      }
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://snip.ly/api/snips/', options);
  
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```

The error message, I receive is:

> Request failed for http://snip.ly/api/snips/ returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"button_action": [{"non_field_errors": ["Invalid data"]}]} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

I would be grateful in case you can help me..

Answer (score 0):

You are configuring the objects with an extra comma on the end.  Try removing the comma:

You have:

```
var button_action =
  {
    "text": button_text,
    "url": button_url,
    "text_color": button_text_color,
    "background_color": button_background_color, 

  }
```

There is an extra comma at the end of:

```
"background_color": button_background_color,
```

That's an incorrect syntax.  I'm not saying that is the problem, but I'd start there first.